# Why my JQuery code doesn't work after data loading through ajax?

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I have a tree view with this jquery code :

```
$(".treeView").on("click", ".CollOpen, .CollClosed", function () {
    $(this).toggleClass("CollOpen CollClosed").nextAll('ul').first().toggle();
});
```

It works correctly when page loaded. When the tree view is changed and then loaded with **Ajax** , it doesn't work ( i have + and - for opened and closed child , but when i click on + or - anything happend ). If i refresh my page it works correctly again.
why ?

could you help me , please ?

Comment: Can you post the corresponding HTML?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With what you've shown, if you're *replacing* the `.treeview` element, then no handler will be set up to handle the new, replacement `.treeview` element.

If that's the case, you can just hook the event on the container of the treeview, basically the first element that doesn't get replaced. E.g.:

```
$(".treeview_container_that_stays_put").on("click", ".treeView .CollOpen, .treeView .CollClosed", function () {
    $(this).toggleClass("CollOpen CollClosed").nextAll('ul').first().toggle();
});
```

You could even use `$(document.body).on(...`, but usually there's an unchanging container closer to what you're working with than that.

Comment: I have problem with $('.treeView').find('ul li:last-child').addClass('lastChild'); ,too. that is not works after ajax load. How can i solved this problem ?

Comment: @Farzaneh: Would have to see an [MCVE](/help/mcve).

Answer (score 2):

Try using the body tag instead of the dynamically modified `.treeview`:

```
$("body").on("click", ".CollOpen, .CollClosed", function () {
    $(this).toggleClass("CollOpen CollClosed").nextAll('ul').first().toggle();
});
```